# GraphAware\Neo4j changes do not appear in remote interface

Tags: php, neo4j, neo4jphp, graphaware

I am currently learning Neo4j. I wrote a first test which creates a Node in Neo4j and fetches it. I use the PHP GraphAware\Neo4j\Client. However I am not able to see that node in the remote interface at http://localhost:7474/browser/, but I am able to fetch the Node in PHP ...

What am I doing wrong?

I create the node with CREATE (n:Person) SET n += {attributes}
and I fetch it with MATCH (n:Person) RETURN n

Comment: can you show some code at least ?

Comment: Thx for your reply. I found the mistake by chance. I had to active Bolt + Routing + the bolt URI in the remote interface. If you do not activate that, the remote interface does only use the browser's local storage I guess. With bolt activated all changes are synchronized.